# Change the color of jQuery slider multiple times when reaching a certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I am trying to make a slider that changes color of the entire background and slider handle when the slider reaches a certain value. I want to have 5 different stages of change. aka. "low- super high bill"

The only slider that I could find that looked similar, is the one on this site: http://www.solarcity.com/

Note: I also want the phrase to change color underneath the slider...such as "This is a low bill" "This is a Medium Bill" How do I change the phrases simultaneously also?

(Sorry I am new to JavaScript)

Here is my jQuery example: http://jsfiddle.net/6Bprf/8/

```
<span class="slider-output" id="monthly_bill">$0</span>/month or <span class="slider-   output" id="yearly_bill">$0</span>/year
<div id="bill_slider"></div>
<div class="customer">
            <div class="low_bill">
                <FONT COLOR="#009900">This is a low bill.</FONT>
            </div>
            <div class="moderate_bill">
              <FONT COLOR="#FFFF00">This is a moderate bill.</FONT>
            </div>
            <div class="medium_bill">
              <FONT COLOR="#FF7519">This is a medium bill.</FONT>
            </div>
            <div class="high_bill">
              <FONT COLOR="#FF3300">This is a high bill.</FONT>
            </div>
            <div class="super_high_bill">
              <FONT COLOR="#FF0000">This is a super high bill.</FONT>
            </div>
        </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function update() {
    var bill_slider = $('#bill_slider').slider('value');
    var yearly_bill = (bill_slider * 12)
    $("#monthly_bill").text(bill_slider);
    $("#yearly_bill").text(yearly_bill);
}

if (monthly_bill < 150) {
greeting = "low bill";
}
if (monthly_bill > 150) {
greeting = "moderate bill";
}
if (monthly_bill > 250) {

greeting = "medium bill";
}
if (monthly_bill > 350) {
greeting = "high bill";
}
if (monthly_bill > 450) {
greeting = "super high bill";
}

$("#bill_slider").slider({
    value: 1,
    min: 0,
    max: 450,
    step: 5,
    slide: function () {
        update();
    }
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks again!

Comment: i can help - u are going to need to change a lot of stuff

Comment: you want it to change the background color on each "bill" condition right?

Comment: check ur fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Bprf/10/ - i changed some things - still dont have background color working but its closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This FIDDLE will get you started - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6Bprf/13/).

I put all of the if/else into the function, and reset the color at the end of each if/else.

I'm not sure you want the whole body to change color, but to each his/her own.

You can play with colors and positioning.

JS

```
var bill_slider;

function update()
{
  $("#monthly_bill").text('$' + bill_slider);
  $("#yearly_bill").text('$' + (bill_slider * 12));
  if (bill_slider < 100)
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(0)').css('display', 'block');
      $('.customer div:eq(0)').css('color', 'yellow');
      $( 'body' ).css('background-color', 'green');
      $('.ui-slider-handle').css('color', 'green');
     }
     else
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(0)').css('display', 'none');
      }   
  if (bill_slider >= 100 && bill_slider < 200)
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(1)').css('display', 'block');
      $('.customer div:eq(1)').css('color', 'green');
      $( 'body' ).css('background-color', 'yellow');
      $('.ui-slider-handle').css('color', 'yellow');
      }
     else
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(1)').css('display', 'none');
     }
  if (bill_slider >= 200 && bill_slider < 300)
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(2)').css('display', 'block');
      $('.customer div:eq(2)').css('color', 'lightblue');
      $( 'body' ).css('background-color', 'gray');
      $('.ui-slider-handle').css('color', 'gray');
     }
     else
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(2)').css('display', 'none');
     }
  if (bill_slider >= 300 && bill_slider < 400)
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(3)').css('display', 'block');
      $('.customer div:eq(3)').css('color', 'blue');
      $( 'body' ).css('background-color', 'white');
      $('.ui-slider-handle').css('color', 'white');         
      }
     else
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(3)').css('display', 'none');
     }
  if (bill_slider > 400)
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(4)').css('display', 'block');
      $('.customer div:eq(4)').css('color', 'red');
      $( 'body' ).css('background-color', 'pink');
      $('.ui-slider-handle').css('color', 'pink');
     }
     else
     {
      $('.customer div:eq(4)').css('display', 'none');
     }
}

$("#bill_slider").slider({
                          value: 1,
                            min: 0,
                            max: 500,
                           step: 5,
                          slide: function (event, ui) {
                                              update();
                                              bill_slider = ui.value;
                                              }
                          });
```